# "could not find the database engine startup handle sql 2008 r2" error

Tags: sql-server-2008, virtual-machines, ssrs-2008-r2

I have hit a brick wall here... I am trying to install ssrs in one of my other VM. After installing sql server express and ssms(which installs successfully), I have tried to install ssrs(making another instance "MSSQLSERVER")... I always get this error...

> could not find the database engine startup handle sql 2008 r2

Here is my log file

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          10/8/2012 12:51:32 PM
Event ID:      7024
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      REPORTING
Description:
The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service terminated with service-specific error Only one      usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted..
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}"    EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
<EventID Qualifiers="49152">7024</EventID>
<Version>0</Version>
<Level>2</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Opcode>0</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-10-08T16:51:32.010000000Z" />
<EventRecordID>6103</EventRecordID>
<Correlation />
<Execution ProcessID="424" ThreadID="2800" />
<Channel>System</Channel>
<Computer>REPORTING</Computer>
<Security />
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="param1">SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)</Data>
<Data Name="param2">%%10048</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

I figured, I need to stop SQLEXPRESS first, so I stopped SQLEXPRESS and tried to reinstall ssrs, it works fine, but now I cannot start SQLEXPRESS... how can I install MSSQLSERVER instance for ssrs, without stopping SQLEXPRESS... please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out... anyone with similar issues, please do not use another instance like I did... just install it as "sqlexpress" and You should not be getting errors... however I had to manually configure ssrs...